# Efficient switch needs self-qualification?

Tags: switch-statement, constants, lookup, kotlin

Apparently, `when` expressions are compiled differently depending on how one denotes constants:

```
object SwitchOverConstants {
    val foo = 1
    val bar = 2
    val baz = 3

    fun one(x: Int) = when (x) {
        foo -> "foo"
        bar -> "bar"
        baz -> "baz"
        else -> "else"
    }

    fun two(x: Int) = when (x) {
        SwitchOverConstants.foo -> "foo"
        SwitchOverConstants.bar -> "bar"
        SwitchOverConstants.baz -> "baz"
        else -> "else"
    }
}
```

Here is the byte code for `one`:

```
   0: iload_1       
   1: istore_2      
   2: iload_2       
   3: getstatic     #15                 // Field foo:I
   6: if_icmpne     14
   9: ldc           #34                 // String foo
  11: goto          40
  14: iload_2       
  15: getstatic     #22                 // Field bar:I
  18: if_icmpne     26
  21: ldc           #35                 // String bar
  23: goto          40
  26: iload_2       
  27: getstatic     #27                 // Field baz:I
  30: if_icmpne     38
  33: ldc           #36                 // String baz
  35: goto          40
  38: ldc           #38                 // String else
  40: areturn
```

And here is the byte code for `two`:

```
   0: iload_1       
   1: tableswitch   { // 1 to 3
                 1: 28
                 2: 33
                 3: 38
           default: 43
      }
  28: ldc           #34                 // String foo
  30: goto          45
  33: ldc           #35                 // String bar
  35: goto          45
  38: ldc           #36                 // String baz
  40: goto          45
  43: ldc           #38                 // String else
  45: areturn
```

How come I need to qualify the constants with the class name to get an efficient table lookup?

Comment: This is a piculiarity of the implementation in the compiler. Not exactly a bug, but we'll likely fix it soon (one way or the other).

Comment: Related issue: [KT-7579](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7579)

Comment: This is more of a bug or feature request than a SO question.  It works best as an issue in [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com), and was nice of @bashor to create an issue tracking it for you.

Comment: to be fair, I'm not creator of the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

You should mark each constant with `const` modifier, then optimization will happen.

By the way, in latest Kotlin version, bytecode for both functions is identical.